kivymd: list in MDNavigationDrawer
I want to place the List in the MDNavigationDrawer component, but I encountered the fact that when adding the "MDListItemHeadlineText" attribute to the "MDListItem" component, the application writes and closes with an error:
Process finished with exit code -1073741571 (0xC00000FD)
How to get around this problem?
from kivy.lang import Builder

from KivyMD.kivymd.app import MDApp
from KivyMD.kivymd.uix.list import MDListItem, MDListItemLeadingAvatar, MDListItemHeadlineText

kv ='''
MDScreen:
    md_bg_color: self.theme_cls.backgroundColor

    MDTopAppBar:
        y: self.parent.height - self.height
        type: "small"
        MDTopAppBarLeadingButtonContainer:
            MDActionTopAppBarButton:
                icon: "menu"
                on_release: nav_drawer.set_state("toggle")
        MDTopAppBarTitle:
            text: "ManDB"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}

    MDNavigationLayout:
        MDScreenManager:
            id: sm
            MDScreen:
                MDButton:
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                    on_release: nav_drawer.set_state("toggle")

                    MDButtonText:
                        text: "Open Drawer1"

            MDScreen:
                name : 'scr2'
                MDButton:
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                    on_release: nav_drawer.set_state("toggle")

                    MDButtonText:
                        text: "Open Drawer2"

        
        MDNavigationDrawer:
            anchor: "left"
            id: nav_drawer
            radius: 0, dp(16), dp(16), 0
            ScrollView:
                MDList:
                    id: menu_list
                    spacing: 10
                    MDListItem:
                        MDListItemHeadlineText:
                            text: 'some text'
                    MDListItem:
                    MDListItem:
'''

class Man(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Man().run()

<ContentNavigationDrawer>:
    ScrollView:
        MDList:
            spacing: 10
            MDListItem:
                radius: [7,]
                on_release:
                    root.screen_manager.current = "scr 1"
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                MDListItemLeadingAvatar:
                    source: "ico/allkits.png"
                MDListItemHeadlineText:
                    text: "some text"
            MDListItem:
                radius: [7,]
                on_release:
                    root.screen_manager.current = "scr 2"
                    root.nav_drawer.set_state("close")
                MDListItemHeadlineText:
                    text: "Screen 2"

MDScreen:
    MDTopAppBar:
        y: self.parent.height - self.height
        type: "small"

        MDTopAppBarLeadingButtonContainer:
            MDActionTopAppBarButton:
                icon: "menu"
                on_release: nav_drawer.set_state("toggle")

        MDTopAppBarTitle:
            text: "Man"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .5}
    MDNavigationLayout:
        ScreenManager:
            id: screen_manager
            transition: NoTransition()
            MDScreen:
                name: "scr 1"

                MDLabel:
                    id: lab
                    markup: True
                    text: "[s]Screen 1[/s] asdsad"
                    halign: "center"
                    theme_text_color: "Custom"
                    text_color: "red"
                MDButton:
                    style: "filled"
                    on_release: app.cl()
                    MDButtonText:
                        text: "Filled"
            #MainScreen:
            #SetsScreen:

        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
            md_bg_color:56/255,40/255,81/255,1
            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                screen_manager: screen_manager
                nav_drawer: nav_drawer

This code works, but it's not very convenient for me
